# Animate the evolution of a Markov Chain on a 2 dimensional array with python matplotlib imshow

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I am trying to write the Metropolis Algorithm for the Hardcore Model on the 2 dimensional lattice. The algorithm I wrote so far seems to work and is as follows:

-Pick a vertex of the 2-d lattice
-Toss a fair coin
-If the coin comes up heads and all neighbors of the vertex take value 0 then set the vertex to 1 otherwise to 0.

I try to animate the evolution of the lattice. Here is what I wrote so far:
The Algorithm to simulate works. The animation not as I want.
Here is the algorithm:

```
    import random 
    from matplotlib import animation
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


    def Nachbarn(x0,x1,B): #test neighbours
        if x1 +1 < len(B) and B[x0][x1+1] == 1 : #top
            return True
        elif x0 + 1 < len(B) and B[x0+1][x1] == 1 : #right
            return True
        elif x1 -1 >= 0 and B[x0][x1 -1] == 1 : #down
            return True
        elif x0 -1 >= 0 and B[x0-1][x1] == 1 : #left
            return True
        else: 
            return False

    def Eckenwahl(B): 
        Länge = len(B)
        x = random.choices(range(Länge),k=2) #choose a vertex
        x0 = x[0]
        x1 = x[1] 
        return x0,x1

    def Münzwurf():
        value = random.randint(0,1) #Toss a coin
        return value

    def MCMC(Array): #MCMC i-te Iteration
        Ecke = Eckenwahl(Array)
        if Münzwurf() == 1 and Nachbarn(Ecke[0],Ecke[1],Array) == False:
            Array[Ecke[0]][Ecke[1]] = 1
        else: 
            Array[Ecke[0]][Ecke[1]] = 0
        return Array
```

Now, initialize the lattice:

```
    N = 10        #Initialisierung of empty lattice
    A = [[0] * N for i in range(N)]
```

If I apply the function MCMC on the array "A" a few times and start the animation with a non-empty lattice:

```
    for i in range(5):
        A = MCMC(A)
```

the animation seems to run, otherwise its stuck in the empty lattice and does not move forward. But I want to start it with an empty lattice. Here are two solutions that have these constraints so far:

Solution 1:

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    im = plt.imshow(A, animated = True)

    def update_fig(*args):
        global A
        B = MCMC(A)
        im.set_data(B)
        return im

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_fig, interval = 1)
    plt.show()
```

Solution 2:

```
    fps = 300
    nSeconds = 10
    fig = plt.figure( figsize=(8,8) )

    a = A
    im = plt.imshow(A)

    def animate_func(i):
        im.set_array(MCMC(A))
        return [im]

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_func, frames = nSeconds * 
    fps,interval = 1000 / fps,)
```

The issue is, everything is ready. I want to start with a 2-d array/lattice that is full with 0`s called the empty configuration then, at time t=1 apply the function MCMC on the array, next display it in the animation and so on for t=2,3,...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, where did you define `FuncAnimation`? can you please provide that as well?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for I reply, I updated the code accordingly. FuncAnimation is imported from Matplotlib. I tried to formulate my question in one sentence at the end to make it clearer :)

Comment: Ah, didn't know that that was a matplotlib function. Have to try it over the weekend :-) today it's too late

Comment: Yeah, great :) I edited the problem a little since I found two half-solutions with constraints since the animation does not run when it starts with an empty lattice.